# How can I fetch only a new remote branch with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-14, git-fetch

I want to fetch a single remote branch that exists on the remote and not on my local machine instead of fetching the entire repository. Basically, the equivalent of `git fetch <remote> <branch-name>` done the first time for a new branch.

I tried clicking `fetch` on the ide and it fetched the entire repository. This is not what I want. I was expecting a modal that would allow me select the branch I want to fetch or if I want to fetch the entire repository.

Comment: What is wrong with just doing a blanket `git fetch` ?